# Uploading file through POST PHP from iOS

Tags: php, ios, post, file-upload, ftp

Hello I want to show you what I'm doing because my PHP or my iOS is not sending the File to the FTP server :S

iOS side:

```
NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *docsDir;
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];
NSString *nombreArchivo = @"wtthdb.db";

NSData *archivo = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:nombreArchivo]]];
NSLog(@"Tamaño del archivo %i",[archivo length]);

NSMutableString *post = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file=%@&filename=%@",archivo,nombreArchivo];
[post appendFormat:@"%@",archivo];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://zsoft.es/subidaios.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *peticion = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLConnection *con;
@try
{
    [peticion setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [peticion setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [peticion setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [peticion setHTTPBody:postData];
    con = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:peticion delegate:self];
    [con start];
}
@catch (NSException *e)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error del servidor"
                                                    message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@",e]
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Aceptar"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
NSLog(@"Empezado");
```

And this is my PHP side:

```
  <?php
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['filename']))
{
    $name  = $_POST['name'];
    $filename  = $_POST['filename'];
    $ftp = ftp_connect("ftp.marinesignal.com");
    ftp_login($ftp, "user", "pass");
    ftp_pasv($ftp, true);
    ftp_put($ftp,$filename,$name,FTP_BINARY);
    ftp_close($ftp);
}
 ?>
```

And I don't know how to debug via XCode my PHP code...

Thanks!!

Comment: Why do you go through a web server instead of uploading directly to the FTP server from iOS?

Comment: Because it's a pain in my ***, there is no FTP lib like java or php... I have been 2 days trying to do this from iOS, and I think via POST and PHP is safe, easy and quick, just i want to make that working...

Comment: Still though, it requires you to have a web server at service for the app. One more thing to maintain. Have you checked you Apples [SimpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/Read_Me_About_SimpleFTPSample_txt.html) demo code? And what is more secure with a HTTP post than FTP? Either work over ssl.

Comment: Yes I have tested lot of FTP samples for iOS as I said I have been 2 days testing things and my Objective-C is not enough to understand all streams and frameworks, because it's so shame to have 5 libs to make a FTP conection then deprecated code as example (not from Apple, but apple code is complicated and didn't work when I put in my project)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to go through this nice article on how to upload a UIImage to the web so you can get an idea on how to prepare and POST the file to the web

http://zcentric.com/2008/08/29/post-a-uiimage-to-the-web/

Then on your PHP Server side you should consider that files are delivered through the $_FILES global variable so you should handle them on this matter

```
<?php
$temporalFolder = "temporal/";

$filePath = $temporalFolder . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $temporalFolder)) {
    echo "The file has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file";
}

$name  = $_POST['name'];
$ftp = ftp_connect("ftp.marinesignal.com");
ftp_login($ftp, "user", "pass");
ftp_pasv($ftp, true);
ftp_put($ftp,$filePath,$name,FTP_BINARY);
ftp_close($ftp);

?>
```

Hope this can give you some insight on your issue